# Class/Object Expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, controllers

I have this in my controller under the index action:

```
format.csv do

    @coasters = Coaster.all
    render text: @coasters.to_csv

end
```

But when I run it I get: undefined method `to_csv' for #   I just can;t see where I am going wrong?

The to_csv method is here:

```
def self.to_csv
    CSV.generate do |csv|
      csv << column_names
      all.each do |coaster|
        csv << coaster.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
      end
    end
  end
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the raise statement?

Answer (score 3):

Your class method `to_csv` works on relations (scopes), so just write `@coasters = Coaster.scoped` instead `@coasters = Coaster.all`:

```
format.csv do

    @coasters = Coaster.scoped
    render text: @coasters.to_csv

end
```

Explanation:

Your method `to_csv` is declared with `self.` so this is class method. This method can be executed only on `Coaster` **class**, not over object or array of objects:

```
 Coaster.to_csv  #good
 Coaster.find(1).to_csv #error - Coaster object: undefined method 'to_csv'
 Coaster.where('id>5').to_csv #good
 Coaster.where('id>5').all.to_csv #error - return array of objects
 Coaster.all.to_csv #error
```

Last 3 lines are related with Rails 3 `ActiveRecord::Relation`: [link1](http://www.asciicasts.com/episodes/239-activerecord-relation-walkthrough), [link2](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/202-active-record-queries-in-rails-3). All class method can be executed on `ActiveRecord::Relation` object, but remember that `Coaster.all` returns array of objects, not relation.

`Coaster.scoped` returns ActiveRecord::Relation for all objects: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods/scoped

Comment: ok, Please could you explain that a bit more. I'm still not fully understanding it. Why doesn't Coaster.all work?

Answer (score 1):

`Coaster.all` returns an array which is not an exception class. So, when you try to raise it you will get the error you are seeing

Comment: Sorry, I posted entirely the wrong piece of code. I have updated my question with what I originally wanted to ask! Sorry guys!